UniRx and UniTask installed cannot find Observable.FromAsync
I have UniRx 7.1.0 and UniTask 2.5.5 installed. I should be able to use Observable.FromAsync as an extension from UniTask but it shows as non-existing method. I got the code from chatgpt and even after asking again, it confirmed it should be there
I have the asm linked so that my code should be seeing them.
I can see both using statement for UniRx and Cysharp.Threading.Tasks working fine.
It's just that one method I am missing.

I hadnt considered observable from async? got any example? - I also thought it was R3 for unity not uniRx..

Oddly, not that Im overly familiar with these packages, I thought uniRx was replaced with R3, so with that in mind with R3 and unitask installed. I get the results you expect.. in fact, heres the code it shows me from the project
    public static Observable<Unit> FromAsync(
      Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> asyncFactory,
      bool configureAwait = true)
    {
      return (Observable<Unit>) new R3.FromAsync(asyncFactory, configureAwait);
    }

    public static Observable<T> FromAsync<T>(
      Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask<T>> asyncFactory,
      bool configureAwait = true)
    {
      return (Observable<T>) new R3.FromAsync<T>(asyncFactory, configureAwait);
    }


R3 is the replacement but older projects would still rely on UniRx. I would need to get it done with UniRx. The usage is to convert the Async methods for UnityService authentication into Observable, it's not compulsory but I'm trying.

You probably mean FromAsyncPattern.
As already mentioned in the other answer there is a newer replacement for UniRX but for those still sticking to it I think that is the equivalent.

I resorted to use ToObservable on the Task method.
